# Failed to determine suitable jdbc url when deploy on gitlab

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, deployment, gitlab

When I run the application locally, it works.

When I deploy the master branch in gitlabs's CI/CD pipeline it works too.

But when I run the deploy to other branch it launch an error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url
Action:
Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles stag are currently active).
```

My application.yml:

```
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${POSTGRES_URL}
    username: ${POSTGRES_USER}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASS}
    hikari:
      connectionTimeout: 20000
      idleTimeout: 20000
      maxLifetime: 60000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      show-sql: true
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        globally_quoted_identifiers: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
```

Comment: Does your CI/CD pipeline define the environment variables POSTGRES_URL, POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASS?

Comment: yes, it is defined, when I deploy the master branch it works, but for other branches it throws this error